# Trouble with $4\times4$ matrix determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & -6 & 7 & 5 \\
    0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
    3 & -2 & -8 & 6\\
    2 & 0 & 5 & 4\\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

Clearly I want to expand along the second row yielding:

$((-1)^5)3$ times the following matrix

$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & -6 & 5 \\
    3 & -2 & 6 \\
    2 & 0 & 4 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

and then breaks down into several smaller matrices:

2 times 
$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    -6 & 5 \\
    -2 & 6 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

and 4 times

$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & -6 \\
    3 & -2 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

which should come out to be $-3[(2(-36+10))+(4(-2+18))]$

$-3[(2(-16))+(4(16))]$

$-3(-32+64)=32 \times -3$

but the answer is -36 I don't know what went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computations are almost correct. But it turns out that $-36+10=-26$, not $-16$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, in your $3\times 3$ matrix, you could have subtracted twice the first column to the last, obtaining instantly the determinant:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & -6 & 5 \\
    3 & -2 & 6 \\
    2 & 0 & 4 \\
    \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & -6 & 3 \\
    3 & -2 & 0 \\
    2 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{vmatrix}=3\cdot 4\quad_\text{(expanding along the last column),}$$
whence the final determinant $-3\cdot 12=-36$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this 4x4 matrix is to row reduce to a triangular matrix with zeros underneath the diagonal.

\begin{bmatrix}1&-6&7&5\\0&0&3&0\\3&-2&-8&6\\2&0&5&4\end{bmatrix}

Row reducing to the triangular matrix yields:

\begin{bmatrix}1&-6&7&5\\0&16&-29&-9\\0&0&3&0\\0&0&0&\frac{3} {4}\end{bmatrix}

From here, we can multiply the numbers in the diagonal:

-(1 $\cdot$ 16 $\cdot$ 3 $\cdot$ $\frac{3} {4}$) = -36